# VBscript and finding input information

Tags: html, scripting, vbscript, client-side, hta

yes I'm a heathen using VBScript client side..Actually I'm fascinated by HTAs and am trying to use VBscript in one... Anyways.. The overall goal of this is to be able to write input to a txt file... I'm running into a error message "Object required" it's pointing back to my FormContent variable I'm using to store the input information... I'm not sure whats going on here, I figure either A) I'm failing miserably B) I don't properly understand how the value is being pulled C) I fail... (Also as a side note I will be addeding in validation later, so don't bark at me :[ Any ideas on what's going on?

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HerpDerp"></HTA:APPLICATION>
     <head>
         <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
         <!--Using VBscript to write data to file (create object, open, append, write, close). -->
         <script type="text/vbscript">
         Sub Submit_OnClick
            dim filesys, filetxt, FormContent
            Set FormContent =  document.getElementById(Text1)
            Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\\MyFile.txt", 8, True) 
            filetxt.WriteLine(FormContent.value)
            filetxt.Close  
        End Sub         

        </script>

     </head>
<form name="Form1">
<p><input name='Text1' style="width: 671px; height: 112px" type='text' id='Text1'></p>
<p><input name='Submit' style="width: 215px" type='button' value='Submit'></p>
</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text1 is a string.  You need to treat it as such (enclose it in quotes).

HOWEVER.... As a general suggestion, don't use HTA.  HTA is an antiquated set of technologies written over a decade ago and pretty much completely unmaintained by Microsoft.

Comment: Derp, Thanks! I was wondering if i needed to format it as such, but kept getting errors with it until I removed the subroutine, but is working now with quotes...Do you have any suggestions on other non-.exe files to make quick an easy apps? I'm not a huge fan of java...

Comment: There are a number of options.  If you want something quick & graphical -- I would just recommend something like C#.  Adobe Air works decently for cross-platform implementations.  I've heard good things about http://www.appcelerator.com, but haven't used it myself.  For most scripting-style things without the need for UI, I just use PHP from the command line.